# Replace table row with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, crud

I encountered an error in replacing my row in my JQuery. This is my code snippet for my JQuery:

```
var newtr = '<td>'+data.row.createdDate+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.emergencyOrderID+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.firstName+' '+data.row.lastName+'</td>'+
                            '<td>('+data.row.latitude+','+data.row.longitude+')</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.pickupLocation+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.hospitalName+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.driverName+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data.row.emergencyStatus+'</td>';
               //$('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID).html('test');
               //alert('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID);
                $('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID).parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

and this is my row:

```
<tr id="tbIDOrder-{{$o->EmergencyOrderID}}">
    <td>{{ $o->CreatedDate }}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->EmergencyOrderID }}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->FirstName }} {{ $o->LastName }}</td>

    <td>({{ $o->Latitude }}),  ({{ $o->Longitude }})</td>
    <td>{{ $o->PickupLocation }}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->HospitalName}}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->DriverName}}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->EmergencyStatus }}</td>
</tr>
```

am i missing something? If it helps, im running this code with Pusher in Laravel :) thanks for your time.

EDIT:
I replaced the script to:

```
$('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID).html(newtr);
```

but it still didnt work

Comment: `$('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID)` is the row. `.parent()` will then be the `<tbody>`. You're replacing the complete `<tbody>` with `<td>`s

Comment: `I encountered an error` - what was it?  Do you mean it simply doesn't work?  What does happen?

Comment: ok I removed the parent( but it still doesnt work.. yeah somehow theres no error, but my javascript to replace the data on the table row is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As `$('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID)` refers to `TR`, You can directly use [`.html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to update the content.

```
$('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID).html(newtr);
```

Here is an example

```js
$('#tbIDOrder-1').html('<td>New Date</td>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tbIDOrder-1">
    <td>CreatedDate</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Cookie, It should

Comment: is there any way i can check again? if it helps im running this with Pusher in laravel, so its supposed to replace on trigger by broadcast..

Comment: Are you generating correct `ID`? Do a `console.log($('#tbIDOrder-'+data.row.emergencyOrderID').length)` to check whether the element exists